# Relative path not working for one element in header menu?

Tags: html, hyperlink, path

I have this code in my new.php file, which is contained within a folder called contacts in my main website:

```
<a href="../index.html" id="header-link">
  <img src="../images/menuslf100logo.png" id="header-img" />
</a>
```

When I go to the website and navigate to contacts/new.php and try to click the link, however, it shows up as contacts/index.html and breaks. Using inspect element, the code shows up like so:

```
<a href="index.html" id="header-link">
  <img src="../images/menuslf100logo.png" id="header-img" />
</a>
```

I honestly have never seen this before. There are three other links in the header that use the same relative path format and they all work perfectly fine. It's just this one that is screwing with me. Has anybody seen this? Is there a fix for it? I've tried deleting the line, saving, and pasting it back in and saving again. No luck. Also tried going with an absolute path by removing the '..'. Didn't change anything. I then moved this link below the next link down just for fun but nothing happened.

Updated with image of file directory:

[image]

Comment: Don't they mean the same thing? If index.html is in a contacts folder in the root,  `../index.html` will go up one directory to the root, which is the same as `index.html`. I think? (Sry, not sure why it's changing.)

Comment: uh, can you post your directory？

Comment: Haven't checked this in a bit but it's up now @Eritquearcus

Comment: @wazz my bad for not posting the directory. index.html is not in the contacts folder, it is in the root. new.php is in the contacts folder, so the relative link should move up one folder to the root to access index.html but instead is attempting to access index.html within the contacts folder where it doesn't exist

Comment: Sry, not sure about my initial comment. I think I was thinking it would be part of a url with a slash before `index.html`, so `https://...../index.html`. Also, still no idea why it would be changing. Maybe add the html to your question of the other links that don't break, fwiw.

Comment: Well turns out there was a confounding factor. I have a global JavaScript file that dynamically updates the link to 'index.html' when the window loads or is resized. This is because at a certain screen size the link is removed so the image linked can be used to activate a dropdown menu but I didn't realize it was screwing up my contacts page. My bad and thanks for the attempts to help